# Message says I can't convert type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I don't want to use the variable.

[image]

I have tried `foreach (Dictionary<int, SalesRecord> sale in SalesRecords)`
but foreach throws the error which says that I can't covert type.

Comment: It says what the type is in the screenshot.

Comment: Yes I was looking at TKey,TValue and trying dictionary<,> instead of this thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `KeyValuePair` to iterate the dictionary in foreach loop

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, SalesRecord> sale in SalesRecords)
{
   SalesRecord salesRec=sale.Value;
}
```